# Delphi - filling pdf form

Tags: forms, delphi, pdf, fill

Is there a free component to   automaticaly fill pdf  forms from Delphi ? I have pdf like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/l0t3caunxtdav2l/P3.pdf?dl=0 and I want programically check the checkboxes, fill the text fields etc

Answer (score 2):

The first place I would search is to see wether Adobe Reader has automation for this, when I did I first found this: [Acrobat Forms Data Format (FDF) Toolkit](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/fdftoolkit.html)

If you download the Windows version, and look in the `FDF Toolkit for Windows\Headers and Libraries\WIN\FdfAcX\` folder, you'll find a DLL that you can register with regsvr32.exe and then access over COM. If you use the Import Type-Library tool from Delphi, you can have it generate a COM/ActiveX wrapper, so you can use the FdfApp and FdfDoc objects.

I should look more into the documentation, but from a quick glance at `FDFACX.IDL`, it looks like you can use `FDFNextFieldName` to find out about field names, and `FDFSetValue` to set their value.

Comment: In case it helps, [this](https://gist.github.com/stijnsanders/527806f66ad3a1139d7d) is what Delphi 7 generates as wrapper. I also found out you need `FDF.DLL`, `FDFTK.DLL` and `FDFACX.DLL` in the same directory in order to have it respond well to regsvr32.

Comment: Hmm I  try the folowing code procedure TfrZadaniaMain.btnWypisyClick(Sender: TObject);
var
Aplikacja : TFdfApp;
Dokument:TFdfDoc;
begin
Aplikacja := TFdfApp.Create(Self);
Aplikacja.FDFOpenFromFile('C:\P3.pdf');
end;  but i get error  "FDFErcBadPDF" :(

Comment: There's more if you look around, [like this](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/FDFtkRef.pdf). I guess the `FDFOpenFromFile` expects a **F**DF file, not a **P**DF, have a closer look at `FDFAddTemplate`

Comment: But i don't have a fdp file,only the pdf.

Comment: See, that's the thing. If I understand correctly, you start a FdfDoc object, set some fields, optionally based in a template (from a PDF), and then save that data into a new FDF file.

Comment: What i want  is ..open the pdf file,fill programically the fields (as i do it manually in acrobat pdf reader) and save the changes (the best to new pdf  file to print it/open on another computer). That's all what i want to do. But I can't find any free tools for delphi  to do that :( Any library I found is "all in one" big tools to do everything with pdf files,but  it cost $300 or more

Comment: BTW the process of filling can be in background (user don't must see the "source" pdf or  process of filling). Best scenario for me : user click button "Fill pdf",  than in background program fill the forms  and after few seconds the  pdf viewer app (for ex acrobat reader) start and show user the filled document.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is free.  Have you looked at [PDFToolKit](http://www.gnostice.com)?

If you happen to, here is a snippet of code illustrating:

```
procedure PrintReceipt(bSaveToFile: Boolean; iInvoicesid: Integer; mDatabase: TAlpineAdoConnection; eaObject: TEAObject);
var
  pdf: TgtPDFDocument;

begin
  try
    pdf := TgtPDFDocument.create(self);
    pdf.LoadFromFile('c:\temp\mypdf.pdf');
    pdf.TextOut('<font size="8">'+'Hello world'+'</font>',630,170);
    pdf.SaveToFile('c:\temp\updated.pdf');
  finally
    pdf.free;

  end;
end;
```

Comment: $350 :(  And is it possible  to use something like item index , in place of  x,y coords ?

Comment: This is an answer to a different question. Asker wants to fill in PDF forms rather than generate PDF files.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  'c:\temp\mypdf.pdf' can already have content.  The "TextOut" will allow you to overlay text on to that content.

Comment: I don't think that counts as filling thee form in

Comment: Filling a form is a totally different thing, you identify form objects by name or index and simply put values on them. Overlaying is a different thing, in that case you must know where to write and once written it can't be edited again, while forms can be opened in a reader and edited.